# Struts 1.2.9 to Struts 2.5.16 migration. getContext() returning NULL

Tags: java, struts2, sitemesh

I am migrating an application written in Struts 1.2.9 to Struts 2.5.16. Sitemesh 2.4.2 is being used to create page using decorator.xml. I have more than one JSP being displayed in body of the page using decorator. While doing so in some pages following error is thrown. Error is being thrown from ServletUrlRenderer class at line 132 which is :

```
ValueStack vs = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();
```

Error:

```
ERROR ClosingUIBean Could not open template
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer.renderFormUrl(ServletUrlRenderer.java:132)
            at org.apache.struts2.components.Form.populateComponentHtmlId(Form.java:229)
            at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:814)
            at org.apache.struts2.components.ClosingUIBean.start(ClosingUIBean.java:52)
            at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:51)
            at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._pages.__adminheader2._jspService(__adminheader2.java:182)
            at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:375)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
            at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:97)
            at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:108)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:129)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:90)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:527)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
            at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.taglib.page.ApplyDecoratorTag.doEndTag(ApplyDecoratorTag.java:230)
            at jsp_servlet._decorators.__adminmoduledecorator._jsp__tag4(__adminmoduledecorator.java:398)
            at jsp_servlet._decorators.__adminmoduledecorator._jspService(__adminmoduledecorator.java:183)
            at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:327)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:375)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
            at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:97)
            at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:108)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:129)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:90)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:527)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
            at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.OldDecorator2NewDecorator.render(OldDecorator2NewDecorator.java:46)
            at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:33)
            at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:375)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at com.vz.cocarrier.webapp.filter.GZIPFilter.doFilterInternal(GZIPFilter.java:42)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at com.vz.cocarrier.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:57)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at com.opensymphony.clickstream.ClickstreamFilter.doFilter(ClickstreamFilter.java:42)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
            at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
            at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:108)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:191)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
            at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:90)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:75)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221
```

Below is my decorator.jsp:

```
<%@ include file="/common/taglibs.jsp"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <%@ include file="/common/meta.jsp" %>
        <page:applyDecorator name="headerDecorator" page="/WEB-INF/pages/adminHeader.jsp" />
        <decorator:head/>
    </head>
    <body<decorator:getProperty property="body.id" writeEntireProperty="true"/><decorator:getProperty property="body.class" writeEntireProperty="true"/>>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header" class="clearfix">
            <jsp:include page="/common/header.jsp"/>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="clearfix">
            <div id="main">
                <%@ include file="/common/messages.jsp" %>
                <c:set var="currentMenuTab" scope="request"><decorator:getProperty property="meta.menuTab"/></c:set>
                <page:applyDecorator name="bodyDecorator" page="/WEB-INF/pages/adminHeader.jsp" />
                <decorator:body/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
            <jsp:include page="/common/footer.jsp"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is extract of my web.xml:

```
*
*
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
*
*
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
*
*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by following the exact order of filters as mentioned in https://struts.apache.org/plugins/sitemesh/. Also in struts.xml I missed to place action type="chain".

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced brackets in the 8th line.

`<body<decorator:getProperty property="body.id" writeEntireProperty="true"/><decorator:getProperty property="body.class" writeEntireProperty="true"/>>`

Probably it should be something like this:

`<body><decorator:getProperty property="body.id" writeEntireProperty="true"/><decorator:getProperty property="body.class" writeEntireProperty="true"/>`

Comment: It is working fine in older version with the same code. It is not a misplaced bracket, it is a way to get body properties through decorator. Issue is with NullPointerException while getting actionContext in ServletUrlRenderer class during rendering the s:form.